# MSSQL space insensitive search

Tags: sql-server, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive

How to make a space insensitive search in SQL Server?

For example those city names should be considered equal:

```
San Remo
Sanremo
```

I know how to make a simple case-insensitive and accent-insensitive search but I found nothing about space-insensitive searches.

There is a collation or a pretty function I can use? Or I should preprocess the city name in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new computed PERSISTED column. This will allow creation of index. Even without an index, this will perform much better than the replace directly on the column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
ADD ComputedCol AS REPLACE(YourColumn, ' ', '') PERSISTED
```

Comment: Thank you. So there is no "magic" collation? I should preprocess data :-)

Comment: there is no collation that ignores characters

Answer (score 0):

You could search on

```
REPLACE (column_name, ' ', '') like '%yourCriteria%
```

rather than just

```
column_name like '%yourCriteria%
```

I would advice against it, since text searches are more resource consuming.
A better option is to add a new column containing the replaced text, index it, and search on that.